# How to add a Facebook Share gate to a Youtube video

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, youtube

I saw a video on a website, but for watching it, you needed to share the video first. I want to add that in my website also. How to do it? 
Eg Website - http://www.top10viral.com/video/amazing-fire-domino-reloaded-the-tower/

Comment: Share gating is not allowed by Facebook platform policy

Comment: Then how does that website get it? Please tell me

Comment: Does it matter? Do you want your website banned from Facebook?

Comment: Ok lol fine. I don't want to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use software's like Bleupage PRO and Tabfu, they also create gates very easy hassle free. You can read a thread that can further shed some light on it and will make you understand better of how you can make share gates using Bleupage PRO software: http://www.warriorforum.com/warrior-special-offers/1207907-bluepage-pro-powerful-social-marketing-software-10-000-sold-limited-time-special-offer.html

Comment: Try providing a real as in detailed answer or add this as a comment. It is more of a hint, than something that solves the problem. Also: links may die out, and answers should be usable for users in upcoming future.